# MySQL find_in_set for results that have all the search strings in the set

Tags: mysql

I have the following SQL query, to search for products in this case:

```
SELECT     sql_cache distinct p.products_id
FROM       products p 
INNER JOIN filter_association_products fap 
ON         p.products_id =fap.products_id 
WHERE      p.products_status = '1' 
AND        date_sub(curdate(),interval 3000 day) <= p.products_date_added 
AND        find_in_set(fap.filter_id,'130,128') 
ORDER BY   p.products_date_added DESC
```

Currently the result I get is all the products that have fap.filter_id 128 and fap.filter_id 130, but I want it to list only products that have **both** of these filters.

Basically I want to use find_in_set to do this:

```
AND (fap.filter_id = '130' AND fap.filter_id = '128')
```

right now the way it functions is:

```
AND (fap.filter_id = '130' OR fap.filter_id = '128')
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: What do you mean @Strawberry ?

Comment: Think I misunderstood- but the answers below seem to have it covered

Comment: Not really covered. I still get the same results as `AND (fap.filter_id = '130' OR fap.filter_id = '128')` instead of `AND (fap.filter_id = '130' AND fap.filter_id = '128')`

Comment: I think maybe you haven't understood the answers given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to solve this you need to tell the sql engine how many matching results you want per type. generally you dont specify the comma delimited elements, but rather use find_in_set for looking for a specific thing in an unknown list of elements. you could easily change that to an `IN()` statement.

```
WHERE p.produccts_status = 1
AND ....
AND fap.filder_id IN(130, 128)
```

its a better standard to write the code with the functions / methods provided that do what they are intended to do. that being said you could keep it as is if you wanted.

you need to add a `GROUP BY p.products_id` and include a HAVING clause to count the number of records

```
HAVING count(p.products_id) = 2
```

I put 2 here because you are only looking for 2 items that have to match
you can easily change this to be however many you are looking for. since its something you are specifically looking for you should be able to specify how many matching rows you want (because you are specifying them in the `IN` statement)

```
SELECT     sql_cache distinct p.products_id
FROM       products p 
INNER JOIN filter_association_products fap 
ON         p.products_id =fap.products_id 
WHERE      p.products_status = '1' 
AND        date_sub(curdate(),interval 3000 day) <= p.products_date_added 
AND        fap.filter_id IN (130, 128) 
GROUP BY   p.products_id
HAVING     COUNT(*) = 2
ORDER BY   p.products_date_added DESC
```

Comment: Thanks, John`'AND fap.filder_id IN(130, 128)` gives me the same exact results as `AND  find_in_set(fap.filter_id,'130,128')`, but that's not my question. I want to find all product_ids that have both filter_id 130 AND 128

Comment: By the way, you misspelled `filder_id`, should be `filter_id` and `produccts_status` should be `products_status`

Comment: @CreativeMind that first part about IN was just a recommendation.. I still answered your question with the HAVING clause part i have at the bottom of the answer.. read the whole thing please

Comment: I may misunderstand your answer then. Trying to add group by gives me sql syntax error. Can you please edit your question with a complete revision of my query?

Comment: Thanks mate, saved my day! :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, actually you need something like this:

```
AND fap.filter_id IN ('130', '128')
GROUP BY p.products_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

The approach is to get all products that do have BOTH numbers, not just exact match. it could be more that 2 actually.

But this is valid in case it isn't possible to have the same `filter_id` and `products_id` twice. So they should be unique.
If not see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150498/sql-statement-to-select-group-containing-all-of-a-set-of-values).